# Flowfiles stuck in queue (Apache NiFi)

Tags: apache-nifi

I have following flow:

`ListFTP -> RouteOnAttribute -> FetchFTP -> UnpackContent -> ExecuteScript`.

Some of files are stuck in queue `UnpackContent -> ExecuteScript`.

`ExecuteScript` ate some flowfiles and they just disappeared: `failure` and `success` relationships are empty. It just showed some activity in `Tasks/Time` field. All of them stuck in queue before `ExecuteScript`. I tried to empty queue, but not all of flowfiles have been deleted from this queue. About 1/3 of them still stuck in queue. I tried to disable all processors and empty queue again but it returns: `0 FlowFiles (0 bytes) were removed from the queue.`

When i'm trying to change Connection destionation it returns:

`Cannot change destination of Connection because FlowFiles from this Connection are currently held by ExecuteScript[id=d33c9b73-0177-1000-5151-83b7b938de39]`

`ExecuScript` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66299777/14628464) (uses Python).

So, I can't empty queue because its always return message that there is no any flowfile, and i can't remove connection. This has been going on for several hours.

Connection configuration:
[image]

Scheduling is set to 0 sec, no penalties for flowfiles, etc.

Is it script problem?

**UPDATE**

Changed script to:

```
flowFile = session.get() 
if (flowFile != None):
    # All processing code starts at this indent
    if errorOccurred:
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
    else:
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
# implicit return at the end
```

Same result.

**UPDATE v2**

I set concurent tasks to 50 and then ran `ExecuteScript` again and terminated it. I got this error:

[image]

**UPDATE v3**

I created additional ExecuteScript processor with same script and it works fine. But after i stopped this new processor and create new flowfiles, this processor now have same problems: it's just stuck.

Hilarious. Is `ExecuteScript` for single use?

Comment: sounds like your script still processing files

Comment: I guess something went wrong. Because it's processing files for 8 hours already.

Comment: I created additional `ExecuteScript` processor with same script and it works fine. I dont really know what is happening with other `ExecuteScript` processor. How to delete these flowfiles... I can't even terminate it, because 0 flowfiles inside processor.

Comment: have you tried obvious thing like restart nifi?

Comment: I can't restart it now, only at night, because we have many working (right now) other processors.

Comment: you got something wrong with the script. btw, what is the value of `nifi.administrative.yield.duration` in `nifi.properties` ?

Comment: 30 sec. Flowfiles disappeared after restarting NiFi. But i still guess, that script have strange behaviour.

Comment: There some other issues in Jython engine due to which we `theres no attribute named x` errors when using imports. Thats due to a bug in Jython Engine. So we converted all our scripts to Groovy and have no troubles after that. Posting this as a comment as it doesn't answer the Original Question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify Your code in nifi-1.13.2 because NIFI-8080 caused these bugs. Or you just use nifi 1.12.1

[image: changes]

JythonScriptEngineConfigurator:

```java
@Override
public Object init(ScriptEngine engine, String scriptBody, String[] modulePaths) throws ScriptException {
    // Always compile when first run
    if (engine != null) {
            // Add prefix for import sys and all jython modules
            prefix = "import sys\n"
                    + Arrays.stream(modulePaths).map((modulePath) -> "sys.path.append(" + PyString.encode_UnicodeEscape(modulePath, true) + ")")
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object eval(ScriptEngine engine, String scriptBody, String[] modulePaths) throws ScriptException {
    Object returnValue = null;
    if (engine != null) {
        returnValue = ((Compilable) engine).compile(prefix + scriptBody).eval();
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Where can I see more information on this? I can't read the text in the small image. Where is this code located? Do things need to be recompiled, or can Nifi just be stopped, make the change, then start it again?