# Apache NiFi. add new CSV field based on existing with modification

Tags: apache-nifi

I have .csv file with several fields. One of them (for example 3th) contains email. How can I add additional filed that will contain only serverName from email field?

Example:

input:

01;city;name@servername.com;age;

result:

01;city;name@servername.com;age;servername;

I guess it possible through ReplaceText processor, but I can't choose correct value in "Search Value" and "Replacement Value" fields.

Comment: You can use `ExecuteScript or ExecuteStreamCommand` processor to access flowfile content and derive columns, please refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281415/modify-csv-with-apache-nifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your flowfile, to a record with the help of [ConvertRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/index.html).
It allows you to pass to a JSON (or something else) format to whatever you prefer.
Then you can add a new field, like the following, with an [UpdateRecordProcessor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/):

[image: UpdateRecird]

I recommend you the following reading:

- [Update Record tutorial](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Update-the-Contents-of-FlowFile-by-using-UpdateRecord/ta-p/248267)