# How can I dump the .parquet data that is in Azure DataLakeStorage to a Microsoft SQL Server database using Nifi?

Tags: sql-server, azure, apache-nifi, parquet, azure-data-lake-gen2

I've been looking for information for a long time and I can't get it. I'm starting to think it can't be done if the .parquet are in Azure DataLake Storage.

I have a folder with subfolders in Azure DataLake Storage. In these subfolders there are many .parquet. I manage to get them out using ListAzureDataLakeStorage + FetchAzureDataLakeStorage combination. Then I try to pass them through a PutDatabaseRecord (which I think is the correct processor for the dump in the DB).

I think I have the PutDatabaseRecord well configured. But when executing it gives me an error: "Failed to process session due to Failed to process StandardFlowFileRecord due to java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null".

I'm not sure I'm using the PutDatabaseRecord right. I thought that PutDatabaseRecord read the flowfiles that came to it interpreting their content as .parquet (it is supposed to use a ParquetReader as a RecordReader), being able to understand the data as records. But it surprises me that it is not necessary to indicate how to interpret the .parquet, nor how to map its columns with those of the DB table. It still doesn't work as I think and it needs the flowfile content to already arrive as records?

The truth is that I can't explain myself better either because I don't really understand what is considered a record in Nifi or how a record is related to a reading of a .parquet.

Either I am missing a processor or something I am configuring wrong. But the only thing I find is the FetchParquet, which seems to be able to read a .parquet and put it into the FlowFile as records. However, it can only be used with ListHDFS or ListFile, which do not allow me to fetch data from Azure Data Lake Storage

After several tests (using the ConvertRecord and QueryRecord processors), I have come to the conclusion that the problem is in the reading that the ParquetReader does of the content of the FlowFiles that arrive. Well, every processor that needs a ParquetReader gives the same error. Downloading the content of the FlowFile that enters the processor that the ParquetReader uses (whatever it is) and using a .parquet viewer I have verified that this content is fine.
Without knowing what to do, I have attached a screenshot of the specific error. I still don't know what "Name" the error refers to.

[Error Name is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnowd.png)

Note: I also posted my problem on Cloudera, perhaps better explained. I leave the link in case someone wants to look at it. (https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-can-I-dump-the-parquet-data-that-is-in-Azure/td-p/316020)

Comment: Have a look at this - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/NIFI-load-data-from-CSV-to-database/td-p/178511

Comment: Have you tried using Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Hello @Nick.McDermaid . The project is already done in ADF. My job is to see if it can be replicated with Nifi. But thanks, of course it would be the most logical thing to do.

Comment: Hello @Vikramsinh Shinde. Thank you very much for the link to Cloudera.

The post that you indicate makes me understand that the flow that I have done (ListAzureDataLakeStorage + FetchAzureDataLakeStorage + PutDatabaseRecord) should be enough, and that all the work of understanding the .parquet must be done by the element that is placed in the "Record Reader" property of the PutDatabaseRecord. In my case this element is a ParquetReader (in the Cloudera post it is a CSVReader). However, my flow is not working. I do not know why. Because the ParquetReader is not very configurable.

Comment: @Sherit - can you view the content of Parquet file using this viewer - https://github.com/mukunku/ParquetViewer/releases  this will give you a better understanding of the data in the file and mapping it to tables.

Comment: Also give it a try using `ConvertRecord` processor to convert data from Parquet to CSV, and observe how the data is being converted. If it looks good in CSV format then instead ParquetReader  you can configure your PutDatabaseRecord to use CSVReader.

Comment: Hi @Vikramsinh Shinde . I had already thought about seeing the content of the .parquet, but I did not find any application. The one you gave me works perfectly. Many thanks. This has allowed me to check something that I already imagined, a column is missing in the .parquet. I need to Nifi add a column called GROUP to each .parquet. The content of this column for all the rows of each parquet has to be output as a substring of the value of the "azure.directory" attribute of the FlowFile. Any idea how to do it? Thanks

Comment: @Vikramsinh Shinde anyway, I don't think the initial failure is because of that, since I have the configuration in the PutDatabaseRecord as:
Unmatched Field Behavior -> Ignore Unmatched Fields
Unmatched Column Behavior -> Ignore Unmatched Columns

Comment: To add GROUP column -  Parquet to CSV using ConvertRecord => Write custom logic to add and derive value of GROUP column using ExecuteScript => PutDatabaseRecord.

How to use ExecuteScript - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281415/modify-csv-with-apache-nifi/66299777#66299777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the closest thing to the error I was getting was found here (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7817). It seems that it is an error related to the creation of the ParquetReader. This makes sense because it would hit any processor that used a ParquetReader. In addition, the FlowFiles did not even enter the processor that used it.

I was using Nifi version 1.12.1. I have downloaded version 1.13.2 and it no longer gives the Name error. In addition, it is seen that the Flow Files already enter the processor. On the download page of the new version (https://nifi.apache.org/download.html) you can access the Release Notes and the Migration Guidance to know what has been fixed with respect to previous versions and with which processors you have to be careful when migrating.

However, even though the data goes into the processor, it still gives me an error, but it is different and I will open it in another post.