# Write header of csv files in Uppercase and add string to every value in Apache Nifi

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have CSV files like this one below. I would like to change the first line to be in uppercase (the special characters should remain the same):

```
id;name;description_jobs;name22
5;James;student;James22
7;John;police-officer;John12
```

The result should look like this:

```
ID;NAME;DESCRIPTION_JOBS;NAME22
5;James;student;James22
7;John;police-officer;John12
```

Comment: Refer to this to read and modify flowfile content - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281415/modify-csv-with-apache-nifi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ReplaceText processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/) and configure it like this:[image].

Pay attention to the "Search Value" which actually takes first line and to "Replacement Value" which makes it upper case.
You will get this output:

```
ID;NAME;DESCRIPTION_JOBS;NAME22
5;James;student;James22
7;John;police-officer;John12
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked instantly and 100% as i wanted it to be :)

Comment: happy to hear that